# How to connect BotFramework's EchoBot to a database?

Tags: c#, botframework, asp.net-core-2.1

So, I created a bot using Azure BotFramework in C# and downloaded source code. The code is in .NET Core V 2.1

Now I want to customize chatbot by connecting it to a database, for that I created added one class DAL.cs, after adding a class, startup.cs file throws an error in ConfigureServices

> 'EchoBot' is a namespace but used like a type

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
 services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

// Create the Bot Framework Adapter.
services.AddSingleton<IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter, AdapterWithErrorHandler>();

// Create the bot as a transient. In this case the ASP Controller is expecting an IBot.
services.AddTransient<IBot, EchoBot>();
}
```

What can I do to connect it to a dababase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens when the namespace and class name are same. You have declared a namespace `namespace EchoBot` which is conflicting with the class name. You will have to rename your namespace to something different. Refer to [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one/) blog to help understand it better.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have a namespace named EchoBot, update your namespace to another to resolve the error